# Understanding the JavaFX WebView threading model

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to understand how the JavaFX threads work. Descriptions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) are not helping much.

For example in code below, the order of printing is always `A` then `B` then `Z`, which suggests that both the `load()` call and the code inside `changed()` are running on the same thread.

But I do not understand, **why will the thread not just exit after the last `Thread.sleep(2000)` (since there is no more work to be done)?**

I would expect the code inside `changed()` to run on a new thread everytime, and am utterly confused as to how this works!

```
public class Test extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State t, State t1) {
        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
          System.out.println("Z"); // <---
        }
      }
    });

    webView.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");

    System.out.println("A"); // <---
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("B"); // <---
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: In short: you are sleeping on the UI thread so no event can be processed (like setting the state of the load worker to SUCCEEDED)...

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer

`start()` and `changed()` run from the "JavaFX Application Thread". This thread is responsible for monitoring the UI for events, dispatching them to user code and repainting the UI. Unlike `Runnable.run()` that when exits, the thread terminates, `start()` is called by the "JavaFX Application Thread" in something like a loop: when `start()` ends, the next iteration is executed. (Actually the iterations run asynchronously/wait for events, so as not to eat all CPU resources, but the loop is OK as a simplified model.)

#### Longer answer

I'll try to explain in a little more detail.

Place print statements as (unindented to stand out):

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
System.out.println("2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        ...
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State t, State t1) {
                        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
System.out.println("3: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            System.out.println("Z"); // <---
                        }
                    }
                });

        webView.getEngine().load("...");

        System.out.println("A"); // <---
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("B"); // <---
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        launch(args);
System.out.println("4: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

Observe the console and the application:

*User action*: Launch the app
*Console*: The following comes out *immediately*:

```
1: main
2: JavaFX Application Thread
```

*Application*: The main window appears... however without the content! Why? Because the "JavaFX Application Thread", that is responsible for painting the UI, is `sleep()`-ing, before point "A".

*Console*: "A" is printed after 2 seconds
*Application*: Still sleeping for "B", still no content in the window

*Console*: "B" is printed after 2 seconds
*Application*: Things come to life, the content starts filling; the UI thread is no longer blocked in `sleep()` so it is free to do its work.

Notice that despite the fact that `start()` is over, `launch()` is *NOT*, so the main thread is alive and well, thus the application is active. After a while, the page is loaded:

*Console*:

```
3: JavaFX Application Thread
Z
```

*User action*: Press close
*Console*:

```
4: main
```

*Application*: The window closes, the application exits

To gain more insight in this topic you can place breakpoints in `main()` and `start()` and observe the various threads that are active.

*Comment*: The observed behaviour from the `sleep()` calls in the UI thread is why you must never perform long-running tasks inside the UI thread, if you want the application to be responsive.